# OpenIdConnectEvents OnAuthorizationCodeReceived not firing

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am signing in with Azure AD in my Dotnet core web application, it is supposed to hit OnAuthorizationCodeReceived event, but it's not fired.

Could you please give some light on this?

```
 public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
            {
                JsonFileConfigurationService config = new JsonFileConfigurationService();
                options.ClientId = config.AzureAdClientId;
                options.Authority = $"{config.AzureAdInstance}{config.AzureAdTenantId}";
                options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
                options.CallbackPath = config.AzureAdCallbackPath;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                var allScopes = $"{_azureOptions.Scopes} {_azureOptions.GraphScopes}".Split(new[] { ' ' });
                foreach (var scope in allScopes) { options.Scope.Add(scope); }

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    // Instead of using the default validation (validating against a single issuer value, as we do in line of business apps),
                    // we inject our own multitenant validation logic
                    ValidateIssuer = false,

                    // If the app is meant to be accessed by entire organizations, add your issuer validation logic here.
                    //IssuerValidator = (issuer, securityToken, validationParameters) => {
                    //    if (myIssuerValidationLogic(issuer)) return issuer;
                    //}
                };

                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnTicketReceived = context =>
                    {
                        // If your authentication logic is based on users then add your logic here
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
                        context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
                    {
                        var code = context.ProtocolMessage.Code;
                        var identifier = context.Principal.FindFirst(config.AzureAdObjectIdentifierType).Value;
                        var memoryCache = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>();
                        var graphScopes = _azureOptions.GraphScopes.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                        var cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
                            _azureOptions.ClientId,
                            _azureOptions.BaseUrl + _azureOptions.CallbackPath,
                            new ClientCredential(_azureOptions.ClientSecret),
                            new SessionTokenCache(identifier, memoryCache).GetCacheInstance(),
                            null);
                        var result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, graphScopes);

                        // Check whether the login is from the MSA tenant. 
                        // The sample uses this attribute to disable UI buttons for unsupported operations when the user is logged in with an MSA account.
                        var currentTenantId = context.Principal.FindFirst(config.AzureAdTenantId).Value;
                        if (currentTenantId == "9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad")
                        {
                            // MSA (Microsoft Account) is used to log in
                        }

                        context.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);
                    },
                    // If your application needs to do authenticate single users, add your user validation below.
                    //OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    //{
                    //    return myUserValidationLogic(context.Ticket.Principal);
                    //}
                };
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been experiencing similar issues with events not seeming to be called.  Unfortunately without seeing more code.  I presume that the method you've supplied is inside a class implementing `IConfigureNamedOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>`.

I'm guessing that you've also proved with breakpoints or logging that the method is actually invoked.

The other thing to try, is to stop assigning a new `OpenIdConnectEvents` instance to `options.Events` (i.e. `options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents`).  The constructor for `OpenIdConnectOptions` assigns a value to the `Events` property, so by reassigning a new instance to this property, you throw away any event hooks that other configuration code might have added.  A lot of the example code I have found online does assign a new instance like you have, but it seems like it could create issues to me.  Alternatively add your event code to the existing instance e.g.

```
options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
{
    var code = context.ProtocolMessage.Code;
    var identifier = context.Principal.FindFirst(config.AzureAdObjectIdentifierType).Value;
    var memoryCache = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>();
    var graphScopes = _azureOptions.GraphScopes.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
        _azureOptions.ClientId,
        _azureOptions.BaseUrl + _azureOptions.CallbackPath,
        new ClientCredential(_azureOptions.ClientSecret),
        new SessionTokenCache(identifier, memoryCache).GetCacheInstance(),
        null);
    var result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, graphScopes);

    // Check whether the login is from the MSA tenant. 
    // The sample uses this attribute to disable UI buttons for unsupported operations when the user is logged in with an MSA account.
    var currentTenantId = context.Principal.FindFirst(config.AzureAdTenantId).Value;
    if (currentTenantId == "9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad")
    {
        // MSA (Microsoft Account) is used to log in
    }

    context.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);
}
```

Of course, this still means that you might overwrite some other handler (i.e. `options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` may have a handler already).  So you could capture it first and await the result e.g.

```
var existingHandler = options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived;
options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
{    
    await existingHandler(context);

    // Your code here...
}
```

Lastly, if you are using the `AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.AddAzureAd` method in your `Startup.ConfigureServices` method, then check that the `ConfigureAzureOptions.Configure` method doesn't assign a new `OpenIdConnectEvents` as per the above discussion.

Answer (score 9):

You should use hybrid mode and set response type to "code id_token", which is "id_token" by default:

`options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken`

Comment: Thanks - this was the reason for the event handlers not hitting.

Comment: In my case , it is not hitting OnAuthorizationCodeReceived event and after adding above code , now it is working correctly.
thanks.

Comment: it is not firing for me, I used .net 4.7 and identity lib 4.42